# How to save using a default or dynamically generated filename in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, save, filenames

How to save using a default or dynamically generated filename in Matlab? I have done something like this below. But my .dat file is saved as filename.dat instead of the filename I generated using sprintf command.

```
filename = sprintf('k2-%d_k3-%d_k4-%d.dat', K2,K3,K4) 
save filename variable -ascii
```

Here, %d would be replaced by the numbers of those variables K2,K3,K4 in my filename.

Comment: [This is answered here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/148-how-do-i-dynamically-generate-a-file-name-for-save-in-matlab)

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax. Please read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#description) (the last point of *Description* in particular)

Comment: Use something like `sprintf('%d-%d-%d.dat', K2,K3,K4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I have found the solution.

```
save(filename, 'variable', '-ascii')
```

does the trick. I had been searching for a while, and it clicks only after I post.